# How to make column equal to computed value

Tags: sql

So I have this sample data:

```
name  | quantity
bike1 | 1
bike2 | 2
bike3 | 3
```

I want to transform it into:

```
name  | sum_quantity
bike1 | 6
bike2 | 6
bike3 | 6
```

Basically want to take the sum of all quantity and set it for each row in the column.

Comment: Mysql or postgresql?

Comment: Postgresql but I think it's the same with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

In **MySQL** you can use a CROSS JOIN with the `SUM`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bikes (
>   `name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `quantity` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO bikes
>   (`name`, `quantity`)
> VALUES
>   ('bike1', '1'),
>   ('bike2', '2'),
>   ('bike3', '3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT b.name, sum_quantity FROM bikes b CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`quantity`) sum_quantity FROM bikes) t1
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | sum_quantity
> :---- | -----------:
> bike1 |            6
> bike2 |            6
> bike3 |            6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e69980c0e76f42d7bafbfd554bf2ee6c)*

In **Postgres** it is the same

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bikes (
>   "name" VARCHAR(5),
>   "quantity" INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO bikes
>   ("name", "quantity")
> VALUES
>   ('bike1', '1'),
>   ('bike2', '2'),
>   ('bike3', '3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT b.name, sum_quantity FROM bikes b CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM("quantity") sum_quantity FROM bikes) t1
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | sum_quantity
> :---- | -----------:
> bike1 |            6
> bike2 |            6
> bike3 |            6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=895e73b48233448c79fc2d0b2c3b4964)*

Answer (score 0):

That's what `sum` in its analytic form is to be used for:

```
select "name", 
   sum("quantity") over () as sum_quantity
from bikes;
```